# Is there such a function $g$?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Is there such $g(x)$ such that $$-\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx= e^{-x^2}$$ where $$g(x)\neq k\frac1{e^{-x^2}}$$

Comment: your 1st formula means $-\frac{x}{h(x)} = (e^{-x^2})' =- 2x e^{-x^2}$ right ?

Comment: what means $\sim$ to you ?

Comment: Proportional. I was asking if there is any other function that maps like the Gaussian function. Seems not. Silly question.

Comment: @ahra Are you ok with my answer below?

Comment: Yes, completely. Thanks!

Comment: @ahra You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has
$$
-\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx=e^{-x^2}, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ then by differentiating one gets
$$
-\frac{x}{g(x)}=-2xe^{-x^2}
$$ giving
$$
g(x)=\frac12\frac1{e^{-x^2}}, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$